# Random selection with criteria in python

Tags: python

I want to (pseudo)randomly select an object from a list that fits a criterion.  I have a function that does this for one criterion I need:

```
from random import randint
def choose(array):
    return array[randint(0,len(array)-1)]
def choose_c(array):
    result = 'r'
    while result[-1] == 'r':
        result = choose(array)
    return result
```

But each time I want a new criterion I need to write a new function.  Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Do all of your criteria fit the same pattern? That is, could you just add an argument to `choose_c` that reflects which symbol you want to reject? In your example you draw samples until you reject `'r'`. Is that the only sort of constraint you will place on what can be drawn, or will the categorical type of constraint change and include different functionality?

Comment: Also, if you are able, consider using some of the other functions in `random`, like `sample`, instead of writing your own.

Comment: No the criteria vary checking different letters and different patterns of letters.

Comment: Then, as per my solution below, it's a good idea to write each criterion as a separate function, but to modify `choice_c` so that it can accept these extra functions as arguments. That way, the basic logic doesn't have to change, and you can plug in new criteria functions as needed. By writing them as different functions, you make the code more modular and reusable, whereas including them as one big chunk of code in a single function would make it harder to change or extend later. This also makes testing easier.

Comment: I'm curious why you are using your own `choose()` when the standard random module provides `random.choice()`.

Comment: The choose function above is actually a smaller part of a much larger choose function that has other parameters for things such as weighting.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to make your `choice_c` function accept a callable, which will be evaluated on the randomly sampled result until it evaluates to `False`, at which point the random sample will be returned.

```
def choice_c(array, criterion=None):
    result = choose(array)
    if criterion:
        while criterion(result):
            result = choose(array)

    return result

def r_criterion(some_sample):
    return some_sample == "r"

def gt5_criterion(some_sample):
    return some_sample > 5

choice_c(array, r_criterion)
choice_c(array, gt5_criterion)
```

This can also be accomplished using `dropwhile` and/or `takewhile` from the `itertools` module, and if this will be used heavily it might be worth making the `choose` function behave as a generator to use this implementation.

```
from itertools import dropwhile

def choose(array):
    while True:
        yield array[randint(0,len(array)-1)]

def choice_c(array, criterion=None):
    gen = choose(array)
    return next(dropwhile(criterion, gen)) if criterion else next(gen)
```

Of course, in both cases, this places the burden on you to write good unit tests, or otherwise ensure that the criterion functions make sense on the array contents, and that any errors are handled correctly, and that you don't loop over an infinite generator in the `while` section ...

Answer (score 1):

Thank you. I found the answer I was looking for:

```
from random import randint
def choose(array):
    return array[randint(0,len(array)-1)]
array = ['foo','bar','baz']
print choose([i for i in array if i[-1] != 'r'])
```

I filter out all the entries that don't fit the criteria and choose from the remaining.

Comment: While this will work, I urge caution. The argument you feed to your `choose` function here is a newly constructed list. If you need to draw samples from it repeatedly, you'll either have to pay the cost to construct the pre-filtered list (as in your solution) or have a slightly less efficient sampling method that involves occasionally rejecting some of the elements (as in mine). You just need to be aware about the tradeoffs between the two in the context you are working in. But yes, for small problems, with limited patterns to filter out, this will work just fine.